# Prove or disprove, limits of antiderivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

If $g(x), f(x)$ are real and continuous, and $g(x)\leq$ $f(x)\leq$$g(x)+\frac{1}{x}$ for every $x>1$.
The following limit is equal to $0$:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \int_x^{x+\sqrt{x}}(f(t)-g(t))\,dt =0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:
$$g(x)\le f(x)\le g(x)+\frac1x$$
then:
$$0\le f(t)-g(t)\le\frac1t$$ so:
$$\int_x^{x+\sqrt{x}}0\,dt\le\int_x^{x+\sqrt{x}}f(t)-g(t)dt\le\int_x^{x+\sqrt{x}}\frac{dt}t$$
now integrate all parts and you get:
$$0\le\int_x^{x+\sqrt{x}}f(t)-g(t)dt\le\ln(x+\sqrt{x})-\ln(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$
now take the limit...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$0\le f(t)-g(t)\le \frac{1}{t}$$ for $t>1$, so if you integrate....

Comment: Yes @tousa1, it is true.